# Read from URL java

Tags: java, url, timeout

I'm trying to read URL in java, and it works as long as the URL is loading in browser.

But if it is just cylcing in the browser and not loading that page when I'm trying to open it in my browser, my java app just hangs, it will probably wait forever given enough time. How do I set timeout on that or something, if its loading for more than 20 seconds that I stop my application?

I'm using [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)

Here is a relevant part of the code :

```
    URL url = null;
    String inputLine;

    try {
        url = new URL(surl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader in;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: mind posting some relevant code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know how u are using the URL class. It would have been better if post a snippet. But here is a way that works for me. See if it helps in your case:

```
    URL url = new URL(urlPath);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
    con.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
    InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 2):

The [URL#openStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) method is actually just a shortcut for `openConnection().getInputStream()`. Here is the code from the URL class:

```
public final InputStream openStream() throws java.io.IOException {
  return openConnection().getInputStream();
}
```

- You can adjust settings in the client code as follows:

  ```
  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
  // setting timeouts
  conn.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeoutinMilliseconds);
  conn.setReadTimeout(readTimeoutinMilliseconds);
  InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
  ```

Reference: [URLConnection#setReadTimeout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29), [URLConnection#setConnectTimeout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29)

- Alternatively, you should set the `sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout` and `sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout` [system property](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html) to a reasonable value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `URLConnection` (or `HttpURLConnection`) to "read from a url" you have a `setReadTimeout()` method which allows you to control that.

Edited after you posted the code:

```
URL url = null;
String inputLine;

try {
    url = new URL(surl);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
BufferedReader in;
try {
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setReadTimeout( 1000 ); //1 second
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you use `URL` then call `openConnection()` on it which returns an `URLConnection`?

Comment: ok i've just added the modified code -- i'm sure you can spot the 2 new lines and the change in the line with `BufferedReader`

Answer (score 0):

You should add internet permission in **AndroidMenifest.xml**

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> ```

and add it in the **main** function:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```