# Java 7 URL connection hangs

Tags: java, java-7

While executing the following under Java 7, the program hangs.  However, it doesn't hang under Java 6.

```
package pkg;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancer");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine())!= null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What might be the reason?

Comment: could you provide an error message or stack trace?

Comment: "While executing the following code on my jdk 7, the compiler hangs up."  Either this code doesn't compile, or compiles and doesn't run as expected.  Which is it?

Comment: No *stack trace* is available, since it just hangs.

Comment: This code is successfully compiled and it is running in Java 6 but not in Java 7.

Comment: Maybe the same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272405/read-from-url-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not guaranteed to work under *any* version of Java. YOu might have gotten luck with a particular Java runtime. The issue is that you're trying to buffer input coming from the network, and this can hang. You must set the buffer size to 1 (effectively turning off buffering) before using `BufferedReader` with a network connection or with `System.in`; otherwise `read()` calls can hang trying to buffer input that's not available, and may never become available. See the (new) second argument to the `BufferedReader` constructor:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()), 1);
```

Comment: I did but to no avail. May it also be dependent upon the operating system? I'm right now using Microsoft Windows XP Professional version 2002, service pack 3.

Comment: Maybe it's just something dumb like the OS "firewall" settings?

Comment: Accepted because I have to do nothing with Java 7 right now. I'm dealing with Java 6. I just wanted to know the reason behind it.

Comment: Answer is incorrect. Changing the buffer size to 1 won't make any difference. BufferedReader will read whatever is there and will block until at least one char is available, no more. See the Javadoc. The two-arg constructor has been there as long as I can remember, which is 1997, and it has no @since annotation, which suggests it's been there all the time.

Comment: Did I say it hasn't been there all the time? The first sentence says that it's not a version-dependent problem.

Comment: this kind of issue happens in jdk 1.4 as well.So if you do not provide timeout, it may go for hang.One solution is using apache httpclient framework that supports timeout.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Yes, you said exactly that. You said the second constructor argument was 'new'. It isn't.

Comment: @EJP -- Ah. I meant it's the one "new" thing in that line of code; I added two characters to his original constructor call.

Comment: The code is hanging on url.openStream(). I am facing the same problem. I have isolated that call and found it hangs sometimes. I have no idea how to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set ReadTimeout to prevent connection hangs.

The Java getInputStream method will block if anything goes wrong with the connection and the thread calling it will lock up.

The method con.setReadTimeout throws a Read Timeout Exception if the getInputStream method times out, and saves the day.

```
    URL urlObj = new URL(url);
    con = urlObj.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(1000);
    con.setReadTimeout(2000);//This is to prevent url connection hangs
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    con.connect();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```